# How to ignore Pandas reorganizing string indexes?

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a dataframe from a nested dictionary which looks like this:

```py
dict = {
  'Loop1': {
    'pv': 1, 'sp': 2, 'op': 3, 'string_mode': 4, 'auto_mode': 5, 'cascade_mode': 'NaN', 'operational': 6, 'operational_min': 1.0, 'operational_max': 10.0
  },
  'Loop2': {
    'pv': 7, 'sp': 8, 'op': 9, 'string_mode': 10, 'auto_mode': 11, 'cascade_mode': 'NaN', 'operational': 12, 'operational_min': 1.0, 'operational_max': 10.0
  }
}
```

when I use `df = pd.DataFrame(dict)` I get this output:

```
                      Loop1    Loop2  
    auto_mode          5        11           
    cascade_mode       NaN     NaN          
    op                 3        9      
    operational        6        12         
    operational_max   10.0     10.0            
    operational_min   1.0      1.0      
    pv                 1       7   
    sp                 2       8        
    string_mode        4       10
```

As you can see the indexes for the dataframe are automatically reorganizing themselves alphabetically.

Is there any way to keep Pandas from automatically reorganizing the indexes so that it preserves the order in the dictionary?

NOTE:
I have tried using pandas.DataFrame.sort_index(dict, inplace=True) and got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_get_axis_number'
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following snippet will give you a dataframe with the index ordered the same way as the keys for the dict `Loop1`, which seems to be what you're after.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Loop1': {'pv': 1, 'sp': 2, 'op': 3, 'string_mode': 4, 'auto_mode': 5, 'cascade_mode': 'NaN', 'operational': 6, 'operational_min': 1.0, 'operational_max': 10.0}, 'Loop2': {'pv': 7, 'sp': 8, 'op': 9, 'string_mode': 10, 'auto_mode': 11, 'cascade_mode': 'NaN', 'operational': 12, 'operational_min': 1.0, 'operational_max': 10.0}}
order = list(d['Loop1'].keys())

df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.T[order].T
df
```

**Output:**

```
                Loop1 Loop2
pv                  1     7
sp                  2     8
op                  3     9
string_mode         4    10
auto_mode           5    11
cascade_mode      NaN   NaN
operational         6    12
operational_min     1     1
operational_max    10    10
```

As you can see I've renamed your `dict` to simply `d` since `dict()` is a python function in itself. Since your datasample ended with `'Loop3':......et` I've only grabbed a subset of your sample.

There's a very simple way to define the order of the *columns* of a pandas dataframe. Not so much when it comes to the rows. So what I'm doing here is to transpose your initial dataframe, define the column order to be the same as the order of the keys of your dict, and then transpose it right back so that the rows (or indexes) end up in the desired order.

Comment: Thank you for the response! That worked perfectly. I had a unique identifier for my dict in the actual code but I just used dict for the example. I'll make sure to use something else in the future.

Comment: @BrianKeith Thanks for the feedback! Glad it worked out for you